# FuelPHP \URI::current() does not get file extension

Tags: fuelphp, fuelphp-routing

My project requires me to know what file extension was used while calling a route.

For example,
If the route was 127.0.0.1/controller/action/filea.json
Then then I would need to have a function that returns ".json" when called from inside action function "get_action".

If the route was 127.0.0.1/controller/action2/fileb.xml
Then then the function should return ".xml" when called from inside action function "get_action2".

Right now, I tried using \URI::current(), but that only gets me "127.0.0.1/controller/action/filea" or "127.0.0.1/controller/action2/fileb"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not the extension is used is controlled by the config key `routing.strip_extension`, which is true by default.

The current extension can be retrieved using `\Input::extension()`.